# Disable Atmosphere version check

Tags: atmosphere

```
INFO  13:27:59.110 [Thread-5] org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework: Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.0.9
```

Is there any way to disable these version checks during Atmosphere startup?

The only relevant thing I found: http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/11890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't configurable and won't be changed, see:

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1356
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/issues/1212
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/pull/1174